# Excuting a binary in current shell

Tags: shell, binaries

I need to check which all environmental variables a binary is using . But when i simply execute the binary using `./binary_file`, the variables don't reflect in `env`'s output as the binary file is getting executed in its own shell.
I cant use `source ./binary_file` also as source only works on scripts and not on binaries.

**Is there anyway i can make a binary to execute in the current shell, or any other method to find the environmental variables this binary is using?**

Comment: I doubt it: source is a feature of some shell interpreters (some use .)

Comment: What do you mean by "environment variables this binary is using"? The variables it reads? The binary is not "in its own shell", it is in its own "process" and environment variables are not propagated upwards, so any changes it makes will not be visible in the shell where you started it If you want to see the variables it tries to access, use `strace` and check the system calls. You could also use strings to see all coded `strings` on the executable and try to guess which of these might be environment variable names.

Comment: Not the normal int,double variables, the environmental variables it accesses /modifies, like using `getenv()`function.
.Yes, i should have told that its getting executed in its own process.
I will check with `strace`.